# Kendo Grid datetime filtering

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, kendo-grid, kendo-datepicker, kendo-datetimepicker

I am using Kendo Grid. The problem I am facing is that I am not able to filter the datetime by selecting any option from filter.

Here is my code:

```
@(Html.Kendo()
    .Grid<IssueViewModel>()
    .Name("grid")
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(c => c.IssuePostedAt).Format("{0:dd.MM.yyyy hh:mm:ss}").Filterable(filterable => filterable.UI("orderDateFilter")).Title("Posted")
            .ClientTemplate("#:kendo.toString(data.IssuePostedAt, \"dd.MM.yyyy hh:mm:ss\")#");
    })
    .Sortable()
    .Pageable(pageable => pageable
        .Refresh(true)
        .ButtonCount(5))
    .Events(events => events.DataBound("onGridDataBound"))
    .Filterable(filterable => filterable
        .Enabled(true)
        .Extra(false)
        .Operators(operators => operators.ForString(str => str.Clear().Contains("Содержит")))
    )
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .WebApi()
        .Model(model => model.Id(i => i.Issue.Id))
        .Sort(sort => sort.Add(i => i.IssuePostedAt).Descending())
        .Read(read => read.Url("/issue/gridData"))
        .PageSize(20)
    )
```

JavaScript:

```
function orderDateFilter(element) {
    element.kendoDateTimePicker({
        format: "dd.MM.yyyy hh:mm:ss",
        timeFormat: "hh:mm:ss"
    });
}
```

This is code in the controller:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("gridData")]
public async Task<ActionResult> GridData([ModelBinder(typeof(DataSourceRequestModelBinder))] DataSourceRequest request)
{
    var filterByUser = HttpContext.GetReferrerParam("name");
    var gridData = await IssuesRepository.Instance.Get(filterByUser); // get all data from DB
    var results = gridData.ToDataSourceResult(request);
    return Json(results);
}
```

DateTime filtering doesn't work at all. `gridData.ToDataSourceResult(request);` always return empty result.

I will be thankful if anybody could help me out in solving my issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: May i know IssuePostedAt datatype.

Comment: @AGH `IssuePostedAt` is `DateTime`